# Use of creating Log in Apache Giraph .

Tags: java, apache, giraph, bigdata

I was reading Simple Shortest Paths Computation class.
Here :
https://apache.googlesource.com/giraph/+/3d4f31343c3686435696e75ce88a75c9bffb024e/giraph-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/examples/SimpleShortestPathsComputation.java

I could not get the use of creating Log in this class . The program runs fine even if I comment all the log related stuff.

Comment: Seems the logging does not affect the result but just _logs_??

Comment: Yeah logging does not affect the results , then why it is used ? I couldn't find it anywhere .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs don't affect on the programs output but they are used to make debugging and analyzing the program easier. For the full list of why we need logs read this:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37294/logging-why-and-what